# "ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" during Bitmask installation

Tags: fedora, software-installation

**Update**: The solution down there works, but Hipchat messed with my system so I would suggest anyone with the same problem to try the solution, and then check if he encounters any of [these issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156319/firefox-icecat-sqlite-version-error-the-application-has-been-updated-but-your).

[I am trying to install Bitmask on my system(Fedora 20) to get the riseup VPN running.

Running ./bitmask after unpacking the tarball gives the following output:

```
Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4]# ./bitmask
No updates found
/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./apps/:/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./lib/
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apps/launcher.py", line 8, in <module>
    from leap.bitmask.app import start_app as bitmask_client
  File "/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./apps/leap/bitmask/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from leap.bitmask.util import first
  File "/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./apps/leap/bitmask/util/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from leap.common.config import get_path_prefix as common_get_path_prefix
  File "/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./lib/leap/common/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from leap.common import certs
  File "/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./lib/leap/common/certs.py", line 26, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "/home/GlaDOS/Downloads/Bitmask-linux64-0.6.1-4/./lib/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The program does not start up because of this(probably), so does anyone have an idea for a solution?]

Comment: Is openssl installed?

Comment: How to solve the error to get the programm running.

Comment: You probably need to install pyOpenSSL package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version of the file `libssl.so.1.0.0` doesn't appear to be available on a stock F20 system. Here's what I get when I search for it on my laptop:

```
$ repoquery -qf */libssl.so.1.0.0
hipchat-0:2.2.1163-1.x86_64
hipchat-0:2.2.1163-1.i386
```

It's only available from this 3rd party package, `hipchat`. So the application you're attempting to build appears to have been written/configured to use this particular version of that library.

I'd be tempted to ask this question on the project's main site, since it seems to be an issue with the source code.

Comment: yum cannot find a package called `hipchat` and there is none listed in the Fedora package database. Can you tell me where to get it from(I probably have to add a repository?)?

Comment: @Merlin - Yes, hipchat is installed from a 3rd party repo. It's a proprietary app. My intent with this A wasn't to have you install hipchat, but rather to run that `repoquery` command on your system. I'd need more info about the app to assist further. That app was built against this library and it doesn't appear to be a standard library in F20.

Comment: Well, I get no output when running `repoquery`.

Comment: It seems to be that Bitmask as of now is rather supposed to be installed on Ubuntu, but still, the stand alone bundle should be install-able on other systems... https://bitmask.net/en/install/linux

Comment: You could just install hipchat to get this library 8-) https://www.hipchat.com/download.

Comment: @sim I did(even though I am not very happy to have to install a non-open source third party software to get the library), but I still get the same error: `ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: You need to add it to your ld search path. Add a file under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with the path to the directory where the .so file above resides, `/opt/HipChat/lib`.

Comment: I added `libssl.so.1.0.0.conf` to the files and put the path `/opt/HipChat/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0` in, but I still get the same error as above.

Comment: @Merlin - it's not the full path to the file, the full path to the directory that needs to be added, i.e. `/opt/HipChat/lib`.

Comment: Restarting and trying ./bitmask again did the job, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @awesome! Glad it's worked around.

Comment: Installing Hipchat probably was the worst advise ever, it messed up my system...! xD But you probably couldn't have known any better... :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156319/firefox-icecat-sqlite-version-error-the-application-has-been-updated-but-your

Comment: @Merlin - sorry to hear that. I have it on several Fedora 19 & 20 systems and have no issues with it. It's been updated several times.

Comment: No problem, you couldn't have known. On the other hand, I am not a fan of proprietary software, so I am not particularly sad about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install openssl-libs first...

After that, libssl.so.1.0.0 should be in /usr/lib

Comment: There only seems to be an equivalent called openssl-devel for Fedora. I installed that one, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I also tried what is suggested here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/broken-update-yum-missing-libssl-so-on-fedora-12-a-799464/ but it does not work and I am not sure how to go about "digging out libssl.so.0.9.8k from the Fedora 11 package".

Comment: My mistake, in Fedora the package is called openssl. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Openssl is installed and at the latest version.

Comment: I don't have a fedora machine at hand, try to install openssl-libs and `ls -l /usr/libs/libssl.so*`

Comment: Here it's lib, not libs, but that probably does not matter. Output: `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Sep  8 00:08 /usr/lib/libssl.so.8 -> libssl.so.1.0.0`

Comment: Forgot to mention: openssl-libs was also already installed and at the latest version.