# Firefox/Icecat: SQLite Version Error: The application has been updated, but your version of SQLite is too old and the application cannot run

Tags: fedora, firefox, sqlite

**Update**:

The error was caused by a software called Hipchat which I installed because I needed a package from it. It not just made Firefox, Icecat and Thunderbird stop running, but also caused my System Settings to crash(crash like in "I couldn't even open them.".)

I don't know if the program only causes the errors on my system, or if it is a general problem, but if you experience the same errors and have Hipchat installed, you might want to uninstall and check f the problem persists.

[System is Fedora 20.

I used Firefox, then closed it, wanted to open it again and the above messages occured (mind you that between the last updates and the error, I restarted my computer at least three times). YUM also says that SQLite is at its latest Version.

I wanted to switch to Icecat anyways, but it gives me the same error, probably because it uses Firefox's code.

I already tried what is suggested here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=520339

```
$ rpm -qa \*xulrunner\* \*firefox\* \*sqlite\*
```

and

```
# rpm -e --nodeps firefox xulrunner
# yum install --disablerepo=updates firefox xulrunner
```

But none of these worked for me.

I'm not sure if a solution for Firefox would work for Icecat, but I will be happy to test it, and just being able to run Firefox for now would be a good thing.]

Comment: Something else is at fault here, IMO. I have F19 & F20 (my primary system that I use everyday) and I have had 0 issues with Hipchat or any of the other applications that you're using. I too use Thunderbird as my primary email client, daily.

Comment: @slm I as well don't think that software,which is explicitly supposed to be install- and runnable on Fedora without problems, causes such issues on its own. A friend of mine always says things go strange on my machine because I am running Fedora on a Mac, but I can't imagine Hipchat is digging so deep into my system that the Mac hardware is a problem.

Comment: @slm That's why I said people should still try it out in the other post. It's just that it took me days to realize it was a problem caused by Hipchat, and I don't want another poor soul with these problems sitting there without a clue.